# win api DoubleBuffering

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I'm not good at winapi field.. so I want to ask your help.

Below is the code.

```
void DrawScreen(HDC hdc)
{
 int x = 0;
 int y = 0;
 BITMAP bit;
 HBITMAP backBitmap;
 HBITMAP hOldBitmap;
 HBITMAP hOldBitmap2;
 HDC backMemDC, MemDc;
 backBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, rt.right, rt.bottom);
 backMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
 MemDc = CreateCompatibleDC(backMemDC);

//hOldBitmap2 = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(MemDc, backBmitmap2);
 FillRect(backMemDC, &rt, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH)); 
 hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(backMemDC, backBitmap);
 for ( y = 0; y < 3; ++y)
 {
    for ( x = 0; x < 3; ++x)
    {
        switch (cChessBoard[y][x])
        {
        case '#':
            iBit = WHITE_BOARD;
            break;
        case '@':
            iBit = BLACK_BOARD;
            break;
            SelectObject(MemDc, hBit[iBit]);

        }//end of switch
        hOldBitmap2 = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(MemDc,hBit[iBit]);
        BitBlt(backMemDC, x*BW, y*BH, BW, BH, MemDc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    }//end of for

}//end of for

hOldBitmap2 = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(MemDc, hBit[PLAYER]);
BitBlt(backMemDC, Player.m_iX*BW, Player.m_iY*BH, BW, BH, MemDc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

//InvalidateRect(hWndMain, NULL, FALSE);
BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, rt.right, rt.bottom, backMemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
ReleaseDC(hWndMain,hdc);
DeleteObject(hOldBitmap);
DeleteDC(backMemDC);
DeleteDC(MemDc);
}
```

As you can see from the code above,  I want to do double buffering.

But I still can not stop flickering... Someone help me please?

Moving to memory dc and moving things to hdc is not right?

Comment: One glaring issue with your code is resource management. You delete objects you do not own, and forget to delete objects you do own. Destroying a device context while you still have objects selected into it you own is a sure recipe for disaster, too. Guessing won't help you solve the issue. Get a [book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X), and take it from there.

Comment: The most basic cause of flicker is WM_ERASEBKGND.   You didn't show any code that intercepts it so likely to be the underlying cause.  If DefWindowProc() handles it then the window gets cleared with the WNDCLASS.hbrBackground brush and you'll draw the bitmap on top of it.  Seeing the window cleared for a while is perceived as flicker.  And it is important to have the bitmap ready to paint.  If it takes too long then the window will be unpainted for a while and that can look like flicker as well.

Comment: Make your life easier and use [buffered paint API](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/vista/article.php/c15709/Using-Windows-Vista-BuiltIn-Double-Buffering.htm) instead of manually creating a memory DC. Although as Hans already wrote, if you don't intercept `WM_ERASEBKGND` (just return TRUE from this message without calling DefWindowProc), you will still have flickering regardless of the buffering.

Comment: If you search StackOverflow for "gdi double buffering" you will find many questions and answers that show the ins-and-outs of how to do this.  If you want a tutorial, I suggest:  http://www.catch22.net/tuts/flicker-free-drawing

Comment: Thank you guys! I just added WM_ERASEBKGND and it worked. But yeah, I should change my code , because of  resource management.